# Will Apache AXIS2 decodes the URL parameters?

Tags: java, apache-axis

We are using Apache Axis 2 in our product. We have exposed some services to the client. Client is hitting the service with UTF-8 encoding of both request parameters key and values. But the values are receiving to the serverend as it is. Consider the below example.

Client: https://abc.xyz.com/service?key=value%20value

Service(server end) : value will be same like value%20value but we are expecting the "value value".

We want to handle the special characters (/,\, space, # , @, &)

Please help if I am missing anything?

Comment: Please share your code and tell us exactly where the issue lies. We can't tell you what's going on without having a look at the source code.

Comment: We have just public class and public methods and we expose that class a service using Axis 2. My question is , will Apache Axis2 decode the url parameters. If Yes, Could you please tell me how?. It will be very helpful.